# Questions about 14.04.1 hashes

Tags: discussion

Recently I have seen three questions about the hashes posted on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes and 14.04.1. The page says:

> To request an update to this list, please open a bug on the ubuntu-docs package in Launchpad.

<strike>I have, hence, filed a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-docs/+bug/1365834</strike> (see update)

I propose that any new questions about 14.04.1's hashes resulting from their absence in that page be closed as off-topic (being a bug report) and with a link to the MD5SUMS for each flavour on [Ubuntu Releases](http://releases.ubuntu.com).

I have also posted self-answered question with the hashes posted in them: [What are the hashes for the various flavours of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/520317/158442) So such questions can also be closed as duplicates.

---

My bug was a duplicate and the original has this [very interesting comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-docs/+bug/1349715/comments/13):

> We need to put an end to this recurring issue.
>   Nobody on the docs team has rights to edit the page, as the person that did has long since left the team.
>   The page should be edited to point to the actual place to find the hashes and then be done with it.

Should we also start recommending people to avoid that page?

Comment: It would be ironic if my own question was closed off-topic. :D

Answer (score 4):

Regardless of the core problem, now that we have an question and answer on the site, we should close duplicates ones as duplicate of it, not off-topic.

Don't confuse people reporting a bug with people who have a question that might be answered by a bug.